# How to delegate Access Control using Glassfish roles/groups indirectly?

Tags: java, authentication, glassfish

I have my company resource for authentication, since this is part of its security policy.
Basicly, it works this way: requesting a desired url, we receive a login/password prompt for authentication. Since we've been validated, the server returns a bean filled with some session attributes which we can inspect and programatically render components and/or grant access for a requested page.

I'm looking for some way to work with this scenario along with Glassfish Security (JEE7 roles and groups), so I can delegate the access control indirectly and use EJB for access control instead of the  progamatically way.

Does anyone knows how can I do it? I also appreciate any book, site and/or link addressing to this scenario.

Thanks in advance.